# Perl module not found, but installed

Tags: perl, module

I installed the Perl module HTML::Template via cpan. Perl itself recognises the Template module, but when I try to use as a Perl CGI script, it triggers the follow error:

```
$ cat /var/log/httpd/error_log

[Tue Feb 14 11:28:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Can't locate HTML/Template.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/perl5/lib/perjl5/ /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/$
[Tue Feb 14 11:28:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/index.pl line 4.
[Tue Feb 14 11:28:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: index.pl
```

My Perl script (index.pl) is as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use lib "/root/perl5/lib/perjl5"; # is it the correct way to include libs?
use HTML::Template; # error line


print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "Hello there!<br />\nJust testing .<br />\n";

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
print $i."<br />"; 
}
```

If I load the script *http://localhost/cgi-bin/index.pl* it retuns a 500 Internal Server Error.

The module is installed and located in */root/perl5/lib/perl5/HTML/Template.pm*

In, fact `$ perldoc perllocal` returns:

```
[...]
   [1mMon Feb 13 16:43:34 2012: "Module" HTML::Template[0m
       ·   "installed into: /root/perl5/lib/perl5"

       ·   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

       ·   "VERSION: 2.6"

       ·   "EXE_FILES: "

[...]
```

It it correctly installe?
If I type `$ perl -e "use HTML::Template`  no error is return

I'm using Fedora 16

> Linux version 3.2.5-3.fc16.i686
> (mockbuild@x86-06.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 4.6.2 20111027
> (Red Hat 4.6.2-1) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Feb 9 02:24:08 UTC 2012

Answer (score 5):

Your `use lib` line has an extra `j`.

```
use lib "/root/perl5/lib/perjl5";
#                           ^
```

so the path does not match what you said later ("The module is installed and located in: /root/perl5/lib/perl5/HTML/Template.pm").

The way to diagnose this would be to copy-and-paste the directory from the error message `/root/perl5/lib/perjl5` then append the module's filename `HTML/Template.pm` to give `/root/perl5/lib/perjl5/HTML/Template.pm`, then look there to see if the file exists.

You would then see that the file did not exist, and could then go on to work out that there was a typo in the directory name.

Also, if you're maintaining your own (CPAN) library, rather than putting `use lib ...` into all your source files, you might want to consider using another mechanism for getting perl to use your library, for example setting the `PERL5LIB` environment variable (which you could set from your shell's start-up file (e.g. ~/.bash_profile)), or using `perl -I...`.

Also if you want to use CPAN you might want to look at the [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/module/local%3a%3alib) module. One handy way to use local::lib is to install your distro's local::lib (e.g. under Debian/Ubuntu, `apt-get install liblocal-lib-perl`), then use that to set up your own private CPAN library. (You *can* bootstrap local::lib from CPAN, but it's easier to do it using a distro package.)

Answer (score -1):

I met the same problem and I find it caused by the path of perl. You need check your perl path:

```
which perl
```

Make sure put it in the first line!
For example, I installed the HTML:Template with the terminal in my Mac, and my perl uses:`/opt/local/bin/perl`. The script should be with:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl -wT
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "Content-type:text\html\n\n"; # -> before use lib

use lib "/root/perl5/lib/perjl5"; # is it the correct way to include libs?
use HTML::Template; # error line   

print "Hello there!<br />\nJust testing .<br />\n";

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
print $i."<br />"; 
}
```

if you have print html in module on folder /root/perl5/lib/perjl5 print on top content type. Alternative separate module in 2 folder. first use lib module no print html

Comment: Putting the `print` before the `use` makes no difference. The `use` happens at compile time and will thus happen before the `print` anyway. A better solution to catching errors while developing (but not production!) man be [CGI::Carp](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Carp).